# Html input type text with slot for each character represented in css

Tags: html, css, input

Is it possible to achieve this result without using a span with border (solid black) for each square and playing with font-weight and font-size?

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Lets see a piece of code you tried so we can try help out

Comment: Yes e.g. table! No one says you need to use span, you can use whatever element you want.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a monospaced font.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: courier;
  letter-spacing: .9em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) calc(1.5em - 2px), black 1.5em);
  background-size: 1.5em 100%;
  padding-left: .4em;
  width: calc(20*1.5em - .6em);
}
```

```html
<label>Name: <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum"></label>
```